# Global non-const variable found?

Tags: c++, constants, scope, llvm

I'm working on a C++ project and have to make sure it compiles on a few different compilers. I'm using VC++ and using the Visual compiler, it compiles fine. But using LLVM, I'm getting this error:

```
EXEC : error : Global non-const variable found '_ZN7complex1iE. This is not permitted.'
```

I don't know what that means. I do have an include that creates a complex number data type, so I'm assuming the error means that somewhere in my code I'm referencing a complex variable that should either be a const or non-global. In my main function, I only create one complex var, and it's initialized in the main func itself, which I though meant that it was a local var, so, I don't understand how that one var is being see as global. In case it's of any use, here's the one line:

```
complex *signal = new complex[100];
```

And here's the complex number include that I'm using: 
header file: http://www.librow.com/articles/article-10/appendix-b-1
implementation: http://www.librow.com/articles/article-10/appendix-b-2

Am I on the wrong trail that of it being a problem with complex number vars? I googled the error and I don't see anything that seems to match.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you also present a stripped down version of main.cpp that reproduces this error?

Comment: hmm... an empty main still errors this way. In the complex.h, there's: "static const complex i; static const complex j;" and in the implementation, there's: "const complex complex::i(0., 1.); const complex complex::j(0., 1.);" (see the links above for the full files.) Is that it?

Comment: This is a linker error, right? Do you know which variable it is complaining about? Is it complex::i? If so, see if taking it outside of complex:: helps. I've never had static members of a class being of the same type as the class itself. Just in case, are you sure this is legal C++?

Comment: "Just in case, are you sure this is legal C++?" It compiles and works beautifully using the VC++ compiler. So I assume it's valid code. It's only the LLVM compiler that's choking.

Comment: "Do you know which variable it is complaining about?" No. The only error is the one above. It doesn't list or link to a line or file.

Comment: Well `_ZN7complex1iE` looks like a decorated version of `complex::i`, so to check that the problem is indeed with `complex::i` I would suggest renaming it to `complex::i1234567` and seeing if the error message changes.

Comment: Huh. Changing "const complex complex::i(0., 1.);" in the cpp to "const complex complex::i123(0., 1.);" and "static const complex i;" to "static const complex i123;" in the h produces the error "error : Global non-const variable found '_ZN7complex4i123E. This is not permitted.'"